# Elastic Search : filter on not_analyzed array field with hyphen not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping as shown :

```js
{
  "info":{
    "properties":{
        "emailids":{
          "type":"string",
          "index":"not_analyzed",
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Sample data insertion :

```js
 $ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/customer/info' -d '{
                       "emailids" : ["primaryemail","secondary-email"]
        
         }
```

When queried with below query

```js
{
 "bool":{
     "must":{
            "term": "primaryemail"
     }
 }
}
```

it matches the document inserted above.

But when queried for "secondary-email" which has a hypen, it returns 0 results.

```js
{
 "bool":{
     "must":{
            "term": "secondary-email"
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the command you used to create the index and the mapping?

Comment: could you post your full query, it kind of looks wrong ?

Comment: i used java API to create the index and mapping ....anyway i found the solution thanks @Val

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

What analyzer are you using? By default the standard query string analyzer will ignore special characters. You will need to create a custom analyzer for this. The following [link helps explain this in more detail](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/configuring-the-standard-tokenizer/8691/4)

[Info on simple Query String Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)